# State-space model: measurement-driven steps?

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I have a time series that seems to be well described by a univariate local level model (a changing bias in human visual perception, sampled at regular intervals). I have a hunch, however, that the underlying random walk is at least partly driven by the measurements themselves. In order to test this hypothesis, I measure two types of time series. The first type is measured at regular steps, every 12 minutes:

```
u(0), u(12), u(24), u(36), u(48), u(60), u(72), ...
```

The second type is measured at partly irregular intervals, alternating between every 6 or 18 minutes:

```
v(0), v(6), v(24), v(30), v(48), v(54), v(72), ...
```

Of course I could compare the 6- and 18-minute steps in the v-series: if they're no different, then nothing really happens to the random walk between the measurements. The trouble is that the measurement noise is large compared to the random walk steps.

Is there some more principled way I could test this hypothesis? For instance, could I fit a modified local-level model in which the even and odd random-walk steps have different variances, and compare the two variances?

Comment: You'll probably get more interest in this question on stats.stackexchange.com.